# Disallow the tagging of questions with both C and C++ tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

A lot of SO users, especially novice or inexperienced programmers who frequently ask questions, are genuinely confused about the differences between C and C++. As such, you frequently find questions that are posted with code that is specific (or should be specific) to one language or the other, but are tagged with both the C and C++ tags.

Now granted, the languages are not entirely dissimilar. C++ is even designed to be [mostly] backwards-compatible with C. But if you're writing C code in C++ and taking advantage of that backwards compatibility, then you're *not really writing C++ code*. And your question should be tagged accordingly.

This issue extends beyond the simplistic difference that "C++ is an object-oriented language". C is not a subset of C++, and C++ isn't simply "C with classes". That language doesn't exist. **One simply does things differently in C++ than they would in C, and vice versa. If the tags don't take that into account, it becomes an unfortunate reality that many of the *answers* don't take that into account.** One might argue that the actual differences between the two languages are somewhat "rare" in common usage, but a site like Stack Overflow is going to attract a lot of questions that are specifically *about* those weird, edge cases that a developer couldn't figure out on her own.

Most importantly, for questions and answers that involve (or quickly can evolve to) "best practices", the recommendations that one would make for C are almost always different from the recommendations for C++. Despite the two languages' syntactical commonalities, the idioms are in many cases so different as to be polar opposites. If syntax were the only concern, tagging questions C and C++ would make as much sense as the duo C++ and C#. But I bet there aren't very many questions with those two tags together (aside from those concerning interop, which obviously don't count...)

From my observation, the worst possible thing is that questions about one language or the other get hastily closed as *duplicates* of questions that are specifically about the *other* language. The issue is that the other question carries *both* tags, so it's natural to assume that it either covers both languages or is about one of those things that remains the same. I've even voted to do this myself and failed to notice the error until someone more careful than I posted a comment highlighting the difference. It's difficult to imagine how many times 5 people have hastily agreed to close a question before noticing the duplicate is actually about the other language, despite carrying both tags and superficially appearing to be a dup. And if C/C++ programmers can make that mistake, imagine how easy it is for smart programmers in other languages to make it.

**Therefore, it seems that we should strongly consider disallowing a question from being tagged with both the C and C++ tags simultaneously**. The relatively small and specific questions for which this would make sense would not be substantially negatively affected by having to choose one tag or the other. This wouldn't have to go into effect for *past* questions if that keeps down the amount of work required to implement it. The primary concern, it seems to me, is *new* questions. At a minimum, we should consider **showing a warning to the asker** when they add both C and C++ tags to a question.

To pre-empt comments that the community could always edit the tags to fix erroneous co-tagging, consider that it's not always obvious from the question which language the asker is hoping to discuss. That forces editors to make a lot of assumptions about the question being asked that may or may not be correct. It seems the goal of editing (even tags) should be to *minimize* the assumptions necessary, not increase them. If the asker is forced to choose the most appropriate tag, she may choose incorrectly, but it seems the chance is greatly reduced. If and when it becomes obvious that someone has chosen incorrectly, an edit easily solves the problem.

Comment: Should similar tags (like `discussion` and `feature-request` on meta) also be mutually exclusive?

Comment: Hypocrite: You favor banning dual-tagged questions, but used "C/C++" in your question.

Comment: @Ben: The implication wasn't that they're the same language. I'm lumping them together for the specific purposes of this question. I think that's clear from the context. "C/C++" modifies *programmers*, not the language itself. It would be no different than saying "C#/Fortran programmers".

Comment: I think you missed my point.  It's absolutely correct to use "C/C++" in that way.  But you provided your own counter-example to a post suggesting "decide whether you're talking about C or C++, it can't possibly be both", because clearly "C/C++" IS both.

Comment: Related: **[How can we stop SO suggesting both C and C++ tags on questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355331/how-can-we-stop-so-suggesting-both-c-and-c-tags-on-questions)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proposed update to C and C++ tag usage wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374306/proposed-update-to-c-and-c-tag-usage-wikis)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

A warning might be useful.  Forbidding dual tagging, definitely not.

Consider: "How do I write a header file so that it can be #included by both C and C++ programs?"

Furthermore, I've seen people retagging questions from `c++` to `c` because they feel no C++-specific features are being used, even when the code invokes different behavior on C vs C++ compilers.  Classic example: "Error on line `int* pi = malloc(sizeof (int));`".  This is a perfectly reasonable issue<sup>1</sup> under C++, and retagging `c` destroys the meaning.

---

<sup>1</sup> No, using `malloc` as a general purpose allocator in C++ isn't recommended.  But C++ programs often use libraries written in C and may have to pass in buffers which will be deallocated using `free()`.  `new[]` and `free()` are not compatible.  To work with that library the C++ code will need to call the `malloc()` function, which is included in the C++ standard library.  Questions about calling `malloc()` in C++ require the `c++` tag.  Ditto for questions about stdio and many others.

Comment: Agreed. Further reflection indicates that my proposal definitely went too far.  I hadn't revisited the question again until being notified of your answer. I agree that a warning is definitely the better solution. And once such a warning system is implemented, it could be extensible for other potentially "unsavory" tag combinations (if the need were to later arise).

Comment: Note that I also wasn't proposing that *others* retag the question to C. I think that's almost always a mistake. That's why I was searching a way for the original asker to pick the most appropriate tag.

Comment: @Cody: Then exactly what did you mean by "But if you're writing C code in C++ and taking advantage of that backwards compatibility, then you're not really writing C++ code. And your question should be tagged accordingly."?  Cause it sounds like you're saying such questions should be tagged `c`, and I'm telling you, if you using a C++ compiler, the question should be tagged `c++`, regardless of which functions and classes from the standard library are being used or not used.

Comment: Ah, that's a fair point. Hrmm, it's been a while since I wrote the question. I apparently forgot some of the arguments I made...

Comment: Do we need a tag for C/C++ interoperability, and a tag for differences between the languages?

Comment: @dfeuer: Even if you add such a tag (which I think is not a bad idea), it wouldn't make the individual `c` and `c++` tags inappropriate for those questions.

Comment: Actually, compiler specific behavior is compiler specific, and not standard behavior pointed out by the spec. I would only use the standard language tag for questions covered by the specification, otherwise I would opt for compiler specific tags. So be careful when writing "different compiler" or "different language". The example above is definitely not compiler related as your answer somehat implies that, misleadingly. That behavior is well-defined by the standard.

Comment: Based on your reply, it does not seem to be the case that I misunderstanding what you wrote. I am just pointing out we are discussing languages, not compilers as your example implies. In other words, it is slightly confusing what you wrote, and could be improved with focusing on the language rather than the compiler.

Comment: If it was, I would not bring it up, but it is up to you: if you do not want to improve your post, do not improve it. There is no point in arguing if you had already made your mind up. It is clear that this has nothing to do with the compilers, but the standard. Any mentioning of compilers is simply red-herring.

Comment: If you ask the OP what language they are using, someone will argue with them. Only the compiler is a clear test.  That is why I talk about the compiler.

Comment: No! The malloc difference is best-proven by quoting standard material.

Comment: It would not be an "improvement" to return to hand-waving about what language the question is in, which invites the retagging based on what functions from the library are used.

Comment: @FinalContest: And how do you know what standard to refer to?  How do you know what language a question is concerned with?  You look at the compiler.

Comment: No, gcc can compile both, so that will bring you nothing, as well as cl.exe, or I could even mention clang here. What you need to do is to ask the OP about the _language_. We are not discussing compiler tags here and their specific implementations.

Comment: @FinalContest: gcc is a compiler collection, I am talking about which specific compiler is used.  (Which, for unified front-ends, might be controlled by file-name or a "force compile in this language mode" switch)

Comment: @FinalContest: Like it or not, it's easy for the OP to say "I'm using a C++ compiler" and people don't argue with that reality (sometimes they may say "No, you're actually not, because you passed `/Tc`", but they don't argue that the compile is C because the code contains `printf`).  If they say "I'm using C++", they get an argument if the code uses `malloc` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 29):

This wouldn't solve anything.

There are lots of questions that were originally tagged [c] where the OP was clearly using [c++] and there are lots of questions that were originally tagged [c++] and when a C++ solution was given, the OP said "oh, no, I'm using C."

Forbidding a question from being tagged both [c] and [c++] is just silly.  There are plenty of questions that can be asked about both languages (for what it's worth, one of my questions is correctly tagged both [c] and [c++]).

Comment: Well... maybe encourage people who don't know any better to tag them with both. That way an expert who understands the question can come along and retag them.

Comment: This answer is incomplete (and as a consequence, overly negative), because it doesn't address the proposed alternative in the question, which is *"At a minimum, we should consider showing a warning to the asker when they add both C and C++ tags to a question"* I agree with your reasons for not forbidding dual tagging, but I think a warning would address a lot of cases (and they appear to be *very* frequent) where the questioner uses both tags due to inexperience rather than legitimate need (albeit Michael's answer does state some concerns with having a warning).

Answer (score 14):

This seems like a really specific use-case; the engine really needs special functionality added just to detect people using [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) on the same question? If the poster really doesn't know what they're doing, this won't fix anything; they'll add both tags to their question, see the error message (if it's a warning I guarantee it won't even slow them down, take a look at the "this post is subjective and will likely be closed" warning), and delete whichever tag they typed last, so now instead of a bunch of posts with both tags that are [easy to find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20c%2b%2b), there will be a bunch with one tag that should have the other

Comment: It's definitely a specific use case, but that seems like something that afflicts tagging in general. You're probably right about people ignoring warnings, though. My concern isn't that the doubly-tagged questions are difficult to find, it's that they're confusing to everyone and perpetuate the misunderstanding that the languages are the same.

Comment: It would be nice if tags could be marked mutually exclusive with specific other tags.  I could probably come up with a few others, too, particularly ones related to specific versions of software.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, there are some of us who have to do C and C++ interop, eg. when linking with OS and 3rd-party vendors who provide only C libs.  I have ifdef C/cplusplus all over my projects and would not support a blanket ban on using both tags.

Comment: I'm having trouble discerning how your proposed resolution to this, or even your rationale, is different from [mine](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252433/103167)

Comment: @BenVoigt: what Martin is writing, it would be harmful banning tagging both because it would not help certain people. It seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I've agonised over the right tagging myself, for pecisely this reason. I recently asked a question on embedding the the lua scripting language in a c++ application via the supplied c api.

Comment: @PhilLello: Pick your poison: Compile it as C++ and use the supplied headers in C++ as-is, or compile as C and embed them in an `extern "C"`-block.

Answer (score 0):

7 years later, we have finally tried to boil down some cross-posting tag usage policies here:

[Proposed update to C and C++ tag usage wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374306/proposed-update-to-c-and-c-tag-usage-wikis)

I've cast a close vote on this question to point at the linked community wiki instead.

The answers and concerns in this thread were noted and should be in line with the new policies. For example we allow cross-tagging, but with certain rules and restrictions, and also posted guidelines for user moderation of such posts.