# Question tagged C and C++, but only one applicable

Tags: discussion, tags

A related question to this is [Disallow the tagging of questions with both C and C++ tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags), and the consensus was to not disallow both tags in a question.

However, I've seen many questions with both tags where only one language is clearly applicable (e.g. [addresses of characters printed by cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675585/addresses-of-characters-printed-by-cout), it's clearly C++ code).

Should the other tag be removed in this case, or left as-is?

Comment: Are you asking whether invalid tags should be removed from questions?  Really?

Answer (score 7):

In a case like that where it's *very clear* that one tag cannot apply, it's fine to remove it. In most cases it's probably better to ask the OP for clarification in a comment. If they really don't know which language they're using, that's a good place to start troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

4 years later, we have finally tried to boil down some cross-posting tag usage policies here:

[Proposed update to C and C++ tag usage wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374306/proposed-update-to-c-and-c-tag-usage-wikis)

I've cast a close vote on this question to point at the linked community wiki instead. The answer by Bill in this thread is in line with the new policies, where we have added user moderation guidelines: when to prompt the OP for clarification etc.