# Re-tagging C++ questions as C

Tags: discussion, tags

Sometimes questions are posted containing C++ code and tagged either [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c).

So far so good, but then someone comes along and changes the tag to [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) because the code "is not really C++" despite the fact that the code *is* valid C++ according to the C++ standard, and in some cases the code is not even valid C.

For example I have even seen someone delete `#include <iostream>` `using namespace std;` from the OP's posted code and change `[tag:c++]` to `[tag:c]`.

The argument given is something along the lines that because the code mainly uses coding techniques that are valid in both C and C++, then the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) should be preferred. I don't see the logic in that!

I feel that the question should be tagged according to which sort of compiler the poster is using. This is because the poster will want to try and compile the given answers.

There used to be a meta discussion on exactly this topic, with the conclusion that the code should be tagged according to what sort of compiler OP is using, but I can't find it now. (It's not the same as [disallow tagging as both c and c++](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags) although there is some overlap).

Comment: Is this the question you were referring to? -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158450/retagging-c-questions-as-c-without-consulting-asker

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yes that's the one. It's not found at all by searching for "retagging c++ as c" or "retagging c++ questions as c" . it's not even in the complete set of search results

Comment: @Matt: because it isn't on meta.stackoverflow (it should be, though, since it's a site-specific discussion)

Comment: yeah, not sure why it was moved there. That's not where I originally posted it.

Comment: Is it really worth the time spent on discussing such a nuance? I mean, there must be more important things in a programmer's life, surely?

Comment: @lpapp a lot of time gets spent in comment arguments each time such a question is posted .  One could argue that keeping SO well-organized is a good use of time..:)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley the question was moved there because all questions from meta.SO were moved to meta.SE when the new meta.SE was created -- see http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212631/186879

Comment: @MattMcNabb I was replying to Benjamin Lindley on why his question ended up in meta.SE. Matt, if you mind to read the post I've linked, it is a (relatively recent) Dec 19 '13 post -- before then, meta.SO was the meta for the entire SE, and the linked post explains how meta.SO was then moved to meta.SE and SO gained its own meta -- see the "How, precisely, do you plan to do this?" section in the linked post.

Comment: Personally if a user suggests an invalid tag edit to change tags from [tag:c++] to [tag:c] when the post is about [tag:c++] I would submit an edit to roll-back the changes and comment on the post asking both the user who suggested the edit and those who approved the edit *why* they approved it. I've done it before and a few times it has led to a review-ban for those who reviewed the edit and accepted it.

Comment: @cybermonkey often the original editor rolls back the rollback and this goes on and on...  (with both parties having enough rep that the edit doesn't need approval)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I see , that would explain it. So the other thread should have been moved to the new meta.SO in the split but it wasn't for some reason.

Comment: @MattMcNabb In that situation I would raise a custom flag on the question describing what's going on and let a moderator deal with it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb yes, the entirety of the "old" meta.SO was moved to meta.SE and posts specific to the new meta.SO should have been moved back here manually, but of course there are way too many questions to triage one by one and as a result many questions haven't been moved back (yet). I know this is all a bit confusing, sorry if my last comment seemed a bit rude (was too sleepy to word things in a better way).

Comment: New programmers may overlook  questions tagged as C if they are looking for a solution to a C++ problem and they aren't aware of the similarities in the code.  Questions should be tagged for the technology the OP is using.  I'm not a C dev, but I'm assuming C devs know that much of C++ is similar to C when they're searching for answers.

Comment: NOTE: This is a very old thread! Since the community consensus in 2018 [Proposed update to C and C++ tag usage wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374306/proposed-update-to-c-and-c-tag-usage-wikis), the C and C++ tag usage guidance was updated, with recommendations to user moderators regarding cross-tagging. I have therefore closed this as a duplicate. Please use the linked duplicate for any discussion regarding the cross usage of C and C++ tags.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If someone tags a question as C++, then they are intending to write and compile C++ code. Even if the code is horrible, and they have likely compiled it using a copy of UnicornsC++Compiler that does not follow the standard of C++, they still want an answer that makes it work in C++. Retagging it to C is not helpful. OP won't get their intended answer. Furthermore people with a similar problem will see that it is tagged with C and will dismiss the question as irrelevant.

I would say that retagging a question as a different language, and changing the code to fit that language, is a bad practice.

Instead (choose one):

- Close the question as "Unable to reproduce" (with recent and correct compilers)
- Close a question as a duplicate of a canonical Q&A "Compiling with a bad compiler causes all kinds of strange behavior"
- Leave a comment if OP is 100% sure that they are writing C/C++ code, and ask them to change the tag if they mis-tagged it.
- Actually answer the question, for the tagged language. If OP uses outdated, or incorrect code for that language, point that out.

Comment: I agree. In the case of `C` vs `C++`, extreme deference should be given to the tag selected by the OP. It should take overwhelming evidence to change one tag to the other. Even if the code shows clear sign of "the other language", it might not be enough to change the tag (`using namespace std;` with a `C` tag might be an indication that the code is wrong, not that the tag is wrong). I would seek clarification from the OP via comments.

Comment: A problem with this is that too many beginners don´t even know themselves if they want C or C++, or what the differences are. ...

Comment: @deviantfan Maybe, but it's not our job to decide that for them. At most, we should raise it in a comment and let them work it out. Retagging it is just going to result in people answering with the wrong assumption, and those answers being invalidated when the OP clarifies their intent.

Comment: Where can I get a copy of UnicornsC++Compiler?

Comment: @Qix It's part of the Eeeeeek!-package. Hand-drawn circles are not included.

Answer (score 20):

One of the confusing (or do I mean irritating?) scenarios is when the question states it is about C but the code uses features found only in C++ (such as the `<iostream>` header, or a `::` scope qualifier, or `class` or `template`).  If the question is dual-tagged with C and C++, the C tag can be promptly removed — if it uses a C++ feature, it can't be C.

There are fewer features that are strictly C and that can't be C++; many of those are archaic parts of C (such as `main()` with no return type, or a K&R-style non-prototype function definition).  If such code is posted as 'compiling' and is dual-tagged, it is reasonable to remove the C++ tag as it can't be compiled by a C++ compiler.

If either is posted with a single tag, but the tag is the 'wrong' one, it is debatable whether to retag.  Generally, it is best then to solicit input from the person asking the question, trying to establish what they are writing in.  Sometimes they aren't sure, or think they're writing C but they have to be compiling with a C++ compiler because the error messages they get are only valid when the code is compiled by a C++ compiler.  For example:

```
Sometype *obj = malloc(sizeof(*obj));  // Not C++ — requires a cast
```

The statement is valid in C (provided the `<stdlib.h>` header has been included); it is not valid in C++ as there is no implicit conversion from `void *` to other pointer types.  But if they're getting a compilation error on the line about 'cannot convert `void *` to `Sometype *`', then they must be using a C++ compiler, even if they think they're writing C code.

In general, you should give deference to the questioner's views on the language they're using, but some questioners make it hard to keep a straight face.

I generally look strongly askance at dual-tagged C and C++ questions, and usually aim to remove one or the other tags.

Something else to be careful about when closing a question as a duplicate is to ensure that the language tags of the two questions are the same (preferably both with a single tag).  Closing a question tagged C as a duplicate of a C++ question or vice versa is generally a very bad idea.  Where it is appropriate (there are a few cases where it might be acceptable), it probably warrants a comment explaining why — and the comment should be separate from the automatically generated 'possible duplicate' message since those get removed if the question is closed as a duplicate of another.

Comment: Sure, there are a lot of details in the official language specs that can point out if it's C or C++ even if the code is similar. However, I tend to think the intent of OP is what matters. They probably want "stuff" done in "something that compiles" in MSVC or GCC. That is, a solution in C (style) using malloc/void*/etc might be as good as a vanilla C++ solution.

Comment: Just be careful to consider the C++ code in context.  It's perfectly valid for a question about doing something in C to include "and I happen to know that in C++ it can be done like so".

Answer (score 8):

The issue with deleting [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and adding [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) from questions where the code is technically valid C or very close to valid C is doing so dubiously signals to answers that only pure C solutions are wanted. When OP tags their question as [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) it means they want C++ answers (or C answers that work in C++). But changing that to just C rules out the possibility of C++ only answers, possibly contrary to the original intent of the question author.

Comment: The OP should then make it clear that they are using a C++ compiler, in which the C tag should _not_ get added as per current tag usage policies for [tag:c] and [tag:c++].