# How should JNA questions best be tagged?

Tags: discussion

Inciting Question: [How should I pass and return unsigned int by value from Java to C/C++ in jna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544028/how-should-i-pass-and-return-unsigned-int-by-value-from-java-to-c-c-in-jna)

So, I'm trying to solve a common but apparently difficult to google problem in JNA, where my C++ interface uses unsigned ints, and Java is Java.

I'm working in C++, but the problem would apply to any C interface, so anyone who's used JNA would be able to help with this.

However, by tagging with the languages, I have to deal with commenters following those tags who (adorably) think they're helping by explaining to me how signedness works, simultaneously betraying the fact that they don't know Java or JNA at all, and are thus going to be as helpful in this instance as a chocolate teapot.

Based on this experience, I'd be tempted to leave off all the tags except JNA, is this a sensible approach for questions like this?

Related:
[Disallow the tagging of questions with both C and C++ tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252430)

Comment: Isn't it just easier for everyone if you ignore the misguided ones?

Comment: I fully agree to remove the C/C++ tags myself. Dedicated C/C++ enthusiasts should not be bothered with questions about fiddly Java native interfacing that may conflict with what they consider a good idea; that's best served for people who have dedicated insight in the topic of JNA/JNI.

Comment: @Gimby But if we lock the tags down to only what Dedicated C/C++ enthusiasts think are worthwhile questions, we'd untag pretty much the first 5 pages of the [[c]] tag. :-P

Comment: @deworde true that, luckily I didn't post that poorly worded thing as an answer ;)