# How to tag questions about "C with a little C++"

Tags: discussion, tags

Lately, I've seen a couple of C questions "with some C++". Here is one: *[Why does my function only update the struct when I pass it with an & symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831766/how-does-a-void-function-work-with-structures)*

Quote from questions in case it disappears:

> For those asking, we've been taught to code in C using some C++ elements (such as the pass by reference from C++ or cin/cout) to make it easier, therefore it may seem to you that the code is not C nor C++.

How should this be handled? My spontaneous thought is that if you use even the tiniest bit of C++, then you need to compile it with a C++ compiler. This means that you instantly get the restrictions that C++ has, but C doesn't.

I could start a rant about why this is stupid, like that it creates bad habits such as casting `malloc`, but that's not the topic here.

I think that these questions should be tagged with C++ and not C. Am I right? After all, it is not valid C code.

Comment: related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags

Comment: I am inclined to agree with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47831766/how-does-a-void-function-work-with-structures#comment82626661_47831766).. stick to one language at a time

Comment: There are rarely questions that are tagged with c and c++ justifiably. Most of them are carrying one of these tags wrongly, and because of unconciousness that c and c++ are totally different programming languages. If you see a question containing plain c code, edit and remove the c++ tag please. Same vice versa if anything in the question is c++ code, remove the c tag.

Comment: @SurajRao There are rare cases where both tags are justified though. Especially questions aboput interfacing C++ with C code and vice versa.

Comment: @user0042 true. but the current scenario is about mixing C and C++ elements in a very different way

Comment: I would absolutely tag this as C++, but mention that the coding style is "C with a bit of C++". C *and* C++ together is mostly for interfacing between the 2 languages. Since you are compiling with a C++ compiler, tag it as C++

Comment: If there is code that a C compiler will reject but a C++ compiler will (or might reasonably be expected to) accept, it should be tagged C++.  If the code is just C with no distinctive C++ features, it should be tagged C.  I pity the poor student being (mis)taught — that's an appalling teaching methodology.

Comment: I can agree that it should be tagged C++, but should there also be tags for different styles of writing C++? Some other styles might be: using the <algorithms> library and iterators as often as possible, OOP, or template meta-programming.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I think Rakete1111 described it well in his answer. It is not C. It is C-style C++, but still C++.

Comment: Relevant: [Compatibility of C and C++ (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: The example question is about C++ references. It's clearly a C++ only question and should have been tagged as such. A C programmer who knew no C++ could not answer it.

Answer (score 55):

The more fundamental problem is that you are not "*code[ing] in c using some c++ elements*".

You are coding in C++ in C *style*. You have C++, not C, and you should only tag your question with [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Your thought is correct in that regard:

> My spontaneous thought is that if you use even the tiniest bit of C++, then you need to compile it with a C++ compiler.

If you need to compile it with a C++ compiler, then it's not C anymore (because no C compiler would accept the code, if they don't have some extensions).

Comment: The most common comment I see for such a question is along the lines of "[tag:c++] is not [tag:c]". Update the tags to just [c++], inform OP/TC of such, and move on.

Comment: this implies that when i write a bash script and use even a single line of python, my tag would be python? or if i used the jni in a java program, i was actually programming c code?

Comment: @clockw0rk: no. When you use JNI, you have Java program *and* some native code, so you need a Java compiler and a compiler for that native language, hence, tagging with two languages would be justified. (in case, the actual problem is affected by both; sometimes, the problem still is only on one side…) In the example of this question, no `C` compiler is needed. There’s only a `C++` program. It’s not using all features of C++, but which C++ program does this anyway…

Answer (score 36):

In my experience, the community consensus is roughly this:

**The following should be tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) *only*:**

- Code that is pure C with no trace of C++, or code that could be either language.
- Code that is compiled with a C compiler.

**The following should be tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) *only*:**

- Code that contains *any* C++ features. Even though the code may be "C style".
- Code that is compiled with a C++ compiler.

**The following should be tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) *and* [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) both:**

- Questions regarding specific differences between C and C++.
- Questions regarding compatibility or porting code between C and C++.

Questions about code that does not compile in either language (for example combining VLA and iostream), need to be clarified and possibly closed.

---

Notes:

- Questions regarding C++ code that uses C libraries (for example using `extern "C"`), may use both language tags in case it matters for the question, otherwise they should just use [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).
- Questions regarding the use of C libraries (such as pthread.h, windows.h etc) should generally be tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), unless compiled as C++.
- Questions regarding non-standard C extensions should be tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) (including non-standard `gcc -std=gnuXX`, GLib etc).
- Questions regarding non-standard C++ extensions such as [boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost) should be tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).
- Pre-standard C ("K&R") should be tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [kr-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kr-c).
- Pre-standard C++ should be tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).
- The gcc compiler is a C compiler.
- The g++ compiler is a C++ compiler.
- Visual Studio is a C++ compiler.
- C++ compilers may have an option to compile code as pure C. They can then be used in pure [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) questions, *if the C option is set*.
- "Either C or C++ is fine" opinions from the OP is a strong indication of a poor or unclear question. Answers will be very different depending on language picked. Prompt for clarification, perhaps close as unclear/too broad until the OP has clarified this.
- Similarly, questions from a person who doesn't even know which programming language they are using need clarification. Questions from such people are unlikely to make any sense.

Comment: @Stargateur I would however have hoped for more votes (of any kind) to verify that this is really the community consensus among the [tag:c] and [tag:c++] users.

Comment: I don't know if the community consensus is that "Visual Studio is a C++ compiler" (I kid)

Comment: I don't know if it is the actual consensus, but if it isn't, I would strongly recommend that it become the consensus.

Comment: I created a tag that you might want to include in your list. It's called `c++-cstyle`.

Comment: "[c] only": "Code that is pure C with no trace of C++, or code that could be either language." -- That doesn't sound right. If code happens to be written in the common subset of C and C++, but it's compiled with a C++ compiler and answers shouldn't be restricted to what C offers, then tagging the question as [c] seems inappropriate to me. And to you too, apparently, since you contradict it later by saying that questions about code compiled with a C++ compiler should be tagged [c++] only.

Comment: @klutt: "*I created a tag that you might want to include in your list. It's called c++-cstyle.*" The tag you created is the [subject of debate on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372650/734069).

Comment: It is common to write libraries that should compile with a C or C++ compiler. In that case what you are writing is definitely C, but you want to avoid any C-only construct. As per this guide, this would not qualify it for being tagged as both (since it isn't an explicit portability-question), even though any correct solution must respect both language standards.

Comment: @julaine How is writing portable code between C and C++ _not_ a portability question?

Comment: @Lundin My scenario is that somebody asks "How do I do <thing> in C?". It may have several answers, some are C++ compatible and some are not, and I want to know.

Comment: @julaine that sounds like it is covered under "_Questions regarding compatibility or porting code between C and C++._"

Comment: Or, in other words: With C, just like with sql, you usually have more restrictions (and possibilities) than just the language standard, and discussing common restrictions in a question that doesn't explicitly ask for them is a value-add to the site in my opinion. Here is one of the top C-questions, the discussion is full of C++, but there is no C++-tag on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/should-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc