# How to handle edit wars?

Tags: support, edits, edit-wars

Recently I ended up in an edit war. A fairly new user posted a question that was tagged C++. Then a 47k user removed the C++ tag and added a C tag. I linked to this question: [How to tag questions about "C with a little C++"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360709) and changed it back. That user changed it to C again. So an edit war was going on, and that's not good so I decided to not edit anymore.

I then raised a custom flag with the content

> Please resolve the edit war. The consensus seems to be that it should be a C++ tag only.
>   http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360709/6699433

and explained the problem, but my flag was declined with the motivation

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

So how should I have handled it? I cannot see how me and the other user would have resolved the thing.

Note, this is not about if I was wrong or right in the matter. My question is about how to handle edit wars. Also, the user who posted the question resolved it by removing all C++ specific code, which made a C tag appropriate. Later, the user deleted the question so it's definitely a non-issue in this specific case.

Comment: Link to the question? Why can't guess why the flag was declined. Also, don't forget that an autoflag is raised if a certain number of edits is completed in a certain period of time.

Comment: @double-beep Is a link to the question really necessary? I don't want to out people and risk the meta-effect.

Comment: I am unsure if meta is going to touch it. Anyway, we don't have much context to understand who is right and we don't know the other editor's response. Also, we don't have a summary of what the flag contained and therefore can't guess, as mentioned, why it was declined.

Comment: @double-beep The question is not about who is right or not. I have added what I wrote in the flag and the motivation for declining it.

Comment: I think it is OK to flag for a mod and ask for a resolution. The response you got can be read as a general decline, and is the easiest way for a mod to say they think they cannot (or will not) do anything. At that point it is best to leave it be. I think the message may be unhelpful (since the situation really does require mod intervention) and this response would be best reserved when mods are being asked to judge the technical accuracy of an edit. However, there are sometimes cases where the most appropriate tag(s) requires technical knowledge, so that response may be OK in this case.

Comment: @double-beep Besides, the question is deleted so you would need 10k+ rep to view it.

Comment: @klutt - the fact that the question is deleted isn't really a barrier to Meta conversation.  It'd have been nice to see the edit(s) in context so we could see if they were appropriate; as it stands, if the question is deleted, then there's much ado about *nothing* here.

Comment: @Makoto Ok, here it is. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56976396/how-do-i-work-with-strtok-strstr-and-strcmp-in-this-problem

Comment: I think general question is already covered in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322511/edit-war-how-do-i-raise-a-flag-without-getting-declined-by-moderator?rq=1... For the particular case I don't see why there was a need for such involved discussion on question that no one cared even to vote on... and flagging as "pick sides between two high rep users" pretty much guaranteed to be declined...

Answer (score 7):

I agree mostly with Rene's answer, but wanted to add a slightly differing response that probably merits another post. The advice about not pursuing a single rollback is sound - it is a waste of your time. The energy you pour into that could be used to edit twenty other posts, and the latter will generally leave Stack Overflow in a better condition.

However, I often find posts to edit by searching for keywords that are commonly found in low-quality writing. Sometimes I will see the same username coming up, and in those cases, I may be minded to raise a custom flag. My experience is that 95% of posters are reasonable people who are willing to learn and negotiate, and the remainder will continue to produce low-quality or wilfully poor material even after they have been the recipient of several good quality edits. In such cases, it can be helpful to pursue a mod report in order to reduce the amount of material that needs editing.

My advice comes from editing on Stack Overflow for many years, and having had a good result from moderators in response to my custom flags on rollback posts. I take the view that although even difficult contributors can be encouraged or pushed into a more amenable stance, some contributors are so resolutely awkward that locks and suspensions are the only way to handle them.

Of course, try not to let any rollbacks spoil your day, and don't let a flag rejection upset you. Use your judgement, and if you find that editing gets frustrating, step away from the computer for a while. Don't burn out!

Answer (score 5):

Your edit was appropriate: the author originally chose [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) and was using a C++ compiler. The other party was a different user who was trying to change the tag to an inappropriate tag. If I understand correctly, a C compiler **could not compile the code in the question**, and it therefore *broke the provided code*. The asker was definitively *not* asking about [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), but about C++. This furthermore means that the edit conflicted with the asker's intent.

I think your mistake was that you **didn't clarify that the edit invalidated the question**. A better flag message would have been:

> A edit war is being waged. One user has repeatedly changed the language tag to a language that the code is not valid (won't compile) in. Please resolve.

A persistent editor that is invalidating a question is certainly worth bringing to the moderators' attention.

The proper action for users trying to resolve the fact this is C style code would be to comment, as several did. Maybe it is a better question in C than C++. Encouraging the user to switch it to C where they might get better answers is a wonderful idea; if someone is feeling generous, they might even offer to make the edits themselves. But doing this in a manner that makes the code incompatible with the tagged language and not getting agreement from the user is certainly not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't.

Make that one edit that you feel improves the post, provide an edit comment to support your changes, leave an actual comment if you think other casual readers might wonder why an edit is made.

Then you move on. There are plenty of other posts that need your time and dedication. Don't get distracted by this one post where you desperately want to make it right for you. If others think they are more right let them have it. Either someone else will tell them they got it wrong or they see the light in 6 to 8 and undo their damage.

Don't expect a mod to chose between you and the other party involved. They can't. Declining such flags is their safe bet.

Seek some backup in a chatroom if you doubt your own judgement. Or post on Meta to win the "tug war".

Comment: This advice is OK, but I would argue that it is fine to ask for a mod to examine an edit war and to see if they are willing to resolve it. There are surely some rollbacks that are harmful, and mods are generally happy to handle those (including locking the post if required). Although it is good for users to learn how to back down and not worry about minor issues, some users who rollback unfairly really do need a moderator to help them pipe down.

Comment: @halfer rollback wars already raise an automatic mod flag. There is no need to raise one by any of the users involved.

Comment: Thanks Rene, I was not aware of that. How many edits/rollbacks are required for an automatic flag to be raised? Does this have the same severity/weight as a manual flag with a custom explanation?

Comment: @halfer I think it is 2 or 3. it doesn't need much to trigger it.

Comment: You are definitely correct that it would be time economic to spend my time on other questions. On the other hand, there are also many things that I should do instead of hanging on SO in the first place. And I think your answer is a bit problematic. "Let them have it"? The foundation of is collaborate edits to improve posts. Leaving a question because someone is persistent is the opposite of that. And no, I don't "desperately want to make it right for me". I want the issue to be resolved in a good way. Leaving it is not a good way.

Comment: @klutt You asked about how to handle edit wars. I answered that. An edit war ensues when two users have concluded *Leaving it is not a good way*. You can't resolve that on your own. Move on and let the next available party judge the situation. Leave a comment so they know what to look for.