# Is it acceptable to put the Octave tag in a MATLAB post and vice versa?

Tags: discussion, tags

I am aware there are differences between those two. But there are similarities as well.

Answer (score 4):

In general it is not a good idea to tag with both tags unless you are really working with both products at the same time. Tags will tell the answerer in which ecosystem you expect answers and it is simply not helpful to get a Matlab only answer when you're working with octave. Or worse, getting a more complicated answer than necessary because the easiest solution is platform dependent and an answer assumes that the code has to work in both systems.

There is a very similar discussion happening whether [C++ questions can also be tagged with C](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430/disallow-the-tagging-of-questions-with-both-c-and-c-tags) when they ask about shared methods.

Comment: ok then, understood. thank you.